Python Function Reprinting Prior Input() Contents
secret_word = "hello"
guess = ""

def get_guess():
    guess = input("Guess: " )
    if guess.isalpha() is not True:
        print("Please input a letter")
        get_guess()
    if len(guess) > 1:
        print("Please input a single letter!")
        get_guess()
    guess = guess.lower()
    print(guess)
get_guess()

Code above for a school project, when reaching the "print(guess)" line, will print all prior content.
As example, the input chain "3" "2" "ww" "a" will result in 3,2, and ww being denied before accepting a. However, once reaching the "print(guess)", it will print, in order
a
ww
2
3
Any ideas?

After you call get_guess() recursively you continue with the original code. Since guess is a local variable, it prints the old value.

Remember, each recursive invocation has its own scope for local variables. So assigning to guess in the recursion doesn't change its value in the caller.

The function should return the value of guess, then you can do guess = get_guess(). Or don't use recursion for this in the first place, just use a loop. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response

Simply don't have a function call itself to "go back to the top".  This is called recursion and has consequences if you haven't learned to use the technique.  Use a while loop.

after recursively calling itself, the print statement is being executed as there are no conditions for it and every recursive invocation has its own scope for local variables
try using a while loop like:
correct_input = False

while not correct_input:
    guess = input("Guess: ")
    if guess.isalpha() is False:
        print("Please input a letter")
    elif len(guess) > 1:
        print("Please input a single letter!")
    else:
        print(guess)
        break



Don't use recursion (a function that calls itself) if you don't know how to use the technique.
Use a while loop and exit it when the conditions are satisfied.
With a function named get_guess you should actually have a result returned.  Return the guess instead of printing it, then use it by the caller of the function:
secret_word = "hello"
guess = ""

def get_guess():
    while True:
        guess = input("Guess: " )
        if not guess.isalpha():
            print("Please input a letter")
        elif len(guess) > 1:
            print("Please input a single letter!")
        else:
            return guess.lower()  # exit the while loop

guess = get_guess()
print(guess)


"Don't use recursion (a function that calls itself) if you don't know how to use the technique." this is really bad argument tbh - is recursion suitable for this task? would be better question to address.

I understand it's a preference, but I hate the idea of using while True: unless there's really no other option. Recursion fits perfectly this assignment, except the fact that indeed OP needs to get better understanding of how to use it.

@Georgina Recursion is the wrong technique.  Unfortunately Python doesn't have a do/while like C and "looping until you get it right" is perfect for while True.  Many beginners use it as a "goto" without understanding the consequences.  A bad actor can take advantage of it to crash a program by exceeding the stack.

But why - "looping until you get it right" is generally flawed approach - you can overflow memory with while True - I don't think permitting program to run till you run out of memory vs cutting it at build-in recursion depth level (1000 iirc?) is necessarily better? I mean ideally - you put a limit, but then you would use for loop instead.

Unless there is a memory leak in Python, there is no running out of memory with the while loop.

print-s will be scaling up memory, even better if stdout is captured somehow - ultimately you will hit oom, not because of program consuming >100%, but because it being too much on a permanent, uncontrolled basis. Also it's user input quiz exercise, not webserver - steps limit would be at least highly recommended here, and recursive solution is just more aesthetical. You are trying to draw big picture conclusion based on overly simplistic example - the only conclusion I would draw here would be - control execution, and in this case - you likely want to limit steps.

In order to stop current function execution and defer to recursive invocation you have to use keyword return as below:
secret_word = "hello"
guess = ""

def get_guess():
    guess = input("Guess: " )
    if guess.isalpha() is not True:
        print("Please input a letter")
        return get_guess()
    if len(guess) > 1:
        print("Please input a single letter!")
        return get_guess()
    guess = guess.lower()
    print(guess)

get_guess()

Otherwise after successfully running through recursive invocation it will carry on previous run.
